# Include drawing primitives when using CCRenderTexture

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Following this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4421/how-to-mask-a-sprite-with-cocos2d-1-0

And it works. However, for my needs I have to draw some cocos2d primitives in my sprite, and then, mask it.

So I made a subclass of CCSprite, and did this in the draw method:

```
-(void)draw {
    [super draw];
    glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glLineWidth(2.0);
    ccDrawLine(ccp(0,0), ccp(480,320));
}
```

However, when I mask this sprite, the red line appears above everything (including the non-visible area).

I imagine I need a way to include my red line as part of the sprite's texture so that CCRenderTexture can properly take it all, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Since the draw primitives methods are not use Z-order, I think you should draw the line to a seperated rendertexture, and then use the texture to do what you want to.